# WP Rest API returns all results when not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I have a very strange issue for which I could not find the reason. I've created a WP REST API endpoint for posts and some custom post types which returns all posts and can be filtered. Everything works fine locally but in a test environment, while not logged in the endpoint returns all posts no matter the categories or search or sorting I provide to the URL, as soon as I log in everything works fine.

Examples:

```
wp-json/wp/v2/style?per_page=100&style_category=112
```

Should return only 1 post. When the user is logged it does return 1 but as soon as the user logs out it returns all posts. I ran out of ideas so please help :))

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: The enabling for the rest is straight forward -> "show_in_rest" = true;
and the call is with angular js -> const results = await this.$http.get(url);
but the call itself doesn't even matter since you can just type the API endpoint the browser URL and see the results

Comment: could you please show code ` WP REST API endpoint` ?

Comment: I am sorry mate what do you mean by code ` WP REST API endpoint`? as I said enabling the Rest API for Wordpress is easy just "show_in_rest" = true; the WordPress generates the API endpoints

Answer (score 0):

For those interested the issue was server cache. Thanks, guys.